# How to find the first 4 digit number in a string?

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have a string:

```
 $string = "12, 123, 1234, 12345, 56, 567, 5678";
```

And I want to return the **first** *4 digit* number in the string only.

I have a few thoughts on how I could do this, for example using:

```
explode(" ", $string)
```

And then perhaps

```
substr_count()
```

But I am not really sure how to return the first 4 digit number only, I have seen some examples of regex being used, but I don't think that would apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions have this covered:

```
$results = array();
preg_match('/[0-9]{4}/', '1234string', $results);
```

Then your match will be stored in $results[0]

Edit: fixed a coding error.

You can check for matches by saying:

```
$results = array();
if (preg_match('/[0-9]{4}/', '12,3456, 123, 1234, 12345, 56, 567, 5678', $results))
{
    // stuff to do if true
}
else
{
    // stuff to do if false
}
```

Comment: Hey gnack, thanks for the response. this partially works, except unless I am mistaken it only works for that specific string. For example I changed up the string to be:$string = "12,3456, 123, 1234, 12345, 56, 567, 5678"; and it still returns 1234 as the result, any ideas?

Comment: The version of the code that is up there currently definitely returns '3456' as the result if I replace "1234string" the string with your string "12,3456, 123, 1234, 12345, 56, 567, 5678"

Comment: No problem, I did modify it shortly after posting so you may have gotten the initial copy of the code that was buggy.

Comment: Hey one more thing....how best would it be to add a false statement to the end? say if there are no results that match?

Comment: See above - edited the code for you to include testing for a match.

Comment: `[0-9]` boils down to `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

You could explode it with `explode(", ",$string)`, and then loop through the result like this

```
function first4digit($string){
    $nums=explode(", ",$string);
    foreach($nums as $num){
       if(strlen($num)==4){
           return $num;
       }
    }
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/Rhv9ku) is a demo for it

Comment: Thank you for the demo scrblnrd3, however this doesn't seem to work as intended, it only returns "1" as the result

Comment: @user3097967 whoops I was testing out the regex for it